# Simple sql query that matches any database (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some monitoring soft, that able to make to MS SQL DB. if the request was successful - monitoring system says "DB - Ok". If query was unsuccessful, DB - fail.

Also, this monitoring software can pass one parametr to the query. 
So, I need universal query, that can run on any MS SQL DB. If there is any table, or something else, that present in any MS SQL DB?

For example, in each MS SQL instance there is sys.databases. 
Yes, I can create individual script for each DB, that will access to some object in DB. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a table.  You can just use:

```
select 1 as x
```

Or choose a system view:

```
select count(*)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that’s not it. I've created test database "test123", take it offline and when ran you queries, and I've got the same result, as this DB was online. But i need a query, which return error if DB is not accesible (offline, suspect etc.)

Comment: @Posix . . . The information_schema views -- and most system tables -- are database specific.  The issue  may be that you cannot *connect* to the database, so whatever code you are using uses a different database.